# Is there a way to use datediff with literal dates in Firebird?

Tags: sql, firebird

It doesn't seems to work:

```
 select
   datediff(date, '2021-10-10', '2021-10-10') as DAYS_COUNT

 from rdb$database
```

Comment: Why does it not "seem" to work?

Comment: `datetime()` <> `datediff()`

Comment: What a shame! I corrected the question, I pasted the wrong code. Sorry!

Comment: `datediff` has no `date` parameter. Please edit your question to fix this typo, and include the actual error you receive (_"token unknown"_ for your current example, or _"expression evaluation not supported -Expected DATE/TIME/TIMESTAMP type as first and second argument to DATEDIFF"_ for the corrected case.

Comment: You want `day`.  I consider this a typo.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `datediff()` for this, but you need to pass two `date` values. Your example (assuming that `datetime()` is a copy & paste error) passes two string values.

The following works:

```
select datediff(day, date '2021-10-10', date '2021-10-10') as DAYS_COUNT
from rdb$database;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=786890ba9bffc101a5ee04cd6e86eec3)

Answer (score 1):

Is it wrong to use cast ?
You can change timestamp to date or time depending on needs ...

```
select
   datediff(DAY, cast( '2021-10-10' as timestamp), cast( '2021-10-21' as timestamp)
) as DAYS_COUNT

 from rdb$database
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is based on a wrong assumption. The code as shown does not have literal dates, you have string literals that contain something that could be a date. If you need a date literal, you need to prefix the string literal with the keyword `date` to turn it into a date literal.

In other words, you need:

```sql
select datediff(day, date '2021-10-10', date '2021-10-10') as DAYS_COUNT
from rdb$database
```

There are some parts of Firebird - especially in the deprecated dialect 1 - that will automatically attempt to convert strings to dates (e.g. when assigning or comparing to a `date`), but as the second and third parameter of `datediff` are dynamically typed, Firebird doesn't choose for you whether it needs to convert to a `date` or a `timestamp`, you need to specify this yourself.